# How do I call a Fragment from a separate activity to the activity that it's binded to?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So the problem is this:

I have a `MainActivity` with three buttons. When each button is clicked, it's supposed to call its corresponding `Fragment`. All of the fragments are binded to a separate activity called `FragmentsActivity`. How do I call a `Fragment` (which is binded to `FragmentsActivity`) from the `MainActivity`?

These are the original instructions:

**The basic flow of the application should be the following:**

**A `MainActivity` with a logo and menu button**

**If user clicks menu button `ContinentalListFragment` is called which is binded to `FragmentsActivity`. (All `Fragment` are binded to `FragmentsActivity`)**

In more detail:

Here are all the activities and fragments:

- `MainActivity`
- `FragmentsActivity`
- `ContinentalListFragment`
- `ContinentalMealsFragment`
- `MealOrderFragment`

**`ContinentalListFragment`, `ContinentalMealsFragment` and `MealOrderFragment` are all binded to `FragmentsActivity`.**

`MainActivity` has three buttons:

- *Menu*
- *Meals*
- *Order*

The *Menu* button's `onClick()` method is in `MainActivity`, like so:

```
public void showMenu(View view){
    // Call ContinentalListFragment
}
```

When I click the *Menu* button, it needs to call `ContinentalListFragment` as above, which is binded to `FragmentsActivity` with code something like this:

```
public void menuShow(View view){
    fragment = new ContinentalMealsFragment();
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.continentalListContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

and the XML file for `FragmentsActivity` looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/continentalListContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/continentalMealsContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mealOrderContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I really need help with this, I have looked at tutorials but none of them cover how to call a `Fragment` from one activity when it's bound to a separate activity.

Comment: this sounds like a homework assignment... But anyway you don't want to call a fragment in another activity. What you want to do is send data to the activity and have the Activity communicate it to its fragments.

Comment: Hi, it's a practice sample for a mid semester exam. I thought so, because that's what the tutorial showed, so maybe it's a typo or something.

Comment: are you displaying one fragment at a time in FragmentsActivity or all three at once?